# H5P timeline alignment

Tags: wordpress

I have a running website that has a H5P timeline that works really well in chrome but in Firefox its outside the canvas and off to the side. The website is here:

http://www.tunapanda.org

If you scroll down a little bit you will see the timeline developed in H5P. This timeline should show under the heading "Our History". It does this in Chrome, but in Firefox it appears to the right of the heading, to a large part outside the window.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I can't find your content, it seems you have removed it from the page.

If you're still looking to solve the problem I would suggest updating your [H5P timeline](https://h5p.org/timeline) or grabbing it directly from github by getting the [wrapper](https://github.com/h5p/h5p-timeline) and the external [timelinejs library](https://github.com/h5p/timelinejs).

If you still experience problems after this I suggest trying to isolate the problem and put up a [code snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), link to a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or an off-prod site that we can check out to help you further.

Comment: Apparently the website was online and we had to figure out something quick .                                                                                                         A concern I was using page builder for my layout and its not part of the widgets within this plugin.                                                                                       For H5P timeline its working well pretty well in a different site that is hosted locally.